# Custom pipe not be found angular 4

Tags: angular, pipe

I have to implements my custom Pipe in angular 4, but in the component when I try to use this custom pipe I have the following error:

```
<div>{{ selected.lastModifiedDate | formatdate}}</div>
```

> Template parse errors: The pipe 'formatdate' could not be found

my custom pipe at the moment is empty:

**formatdate.pipe**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'formatdate'
})

export class FormatdatePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return null;
  }
}
```

I have a shared pipe module

**pipe.module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormatdatePipe } from '../pipes/formatdate.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  declarations: [FormatdatePipe],
  exports: [FormatdatePipe],
})

export class PipeModule {

  static forRoot() {
    return {
      ngModule: PipeModule,
      providers: [],
    };
  }
}
```

And in my principal app module

**app.module**

```
import { PipeModule } from './shared/pipes/pipe.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    PipeModule.forRoot(),
....
```

Where is the problem? maybe something in the module

Comment: Is there any reason you've created a pipe module? This is unnecessary. You just need to include the pipe in your app.module declarations. https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular2/1165/pipes/3756/custom-pipes#t=201706301331556332039

Comment: it doesn't change, I've created module because I already have this error

Comment: It works if I import the formatdate.pipe in the declarations of every child module

Comment: You have to import it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153370/why-lazy-loaded-module-has-to-import-commonmodule-angular-2/43153529#43153529

Answer (score 3):

You need to import the module in your `declarations` of `app.module`, not the imports.

```
import { PipeModule } from './shared/pipes/pipe.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PipeModule.forRoot()
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    .......
```

Comment: Argument of type '{ declarations: (typeof AppComponent | { ngModule: typeof PipeModule; providers: any[]; })[]; imp...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NgModule'. Types of property 'declarations' are incompatible. Type '(typeof AppComponent | { ngModule: typeof PipeModule; providers: any[]; })[]' is not assignable to type '(any[] | Type<any>)[]'. Type 'typeof AppComponent | { ngModule: typeof PipeModule; providers: any[]; }' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type<any>'. Type '{ ngModule: typeof PipeModule; providers: any[]; }' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type<any>'.

Comment: Why do you think so?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your Pipe to the `providers` array of your pipe module, not just the `declarations` and `exports`.

Making a separate module for the Pipe **is not required**, but is definitely an alternative as you've done. Check the official docs footnote: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes

> You use your custom pipe the same way you use built-in pipes.
>   You must include your pipe in the declarations array of the AppModule . 
>   If you choose to inject your pipe into a class, you must provide it in the providers array of your NgModule.

All you have to do is add your pipe to the **declarations** array, and the **providers** array in the `module` where you want to use the Pipe.

```
declarations: [
...
CustomPipe,
...
],
providers: [
...
CustomPipe,
...
]
```