# ngx-bootstrap CarouselModule not working

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am trying to use carousel module in my angular2 application.
here is my app.ts file.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {CarouselModule}  from 'ngx-bootstrap/carousel';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {AppRoutesModule} from './app.routes';
import { NavbarComponent } from './shared/components/navbar/navbar.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  NavbarComponent,
],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  AppRoutesModule,
  FormsModule,
  CarouselModule.forRoot()
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Bellow is my home.component.ts and home.component.html in which i am using the module

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

HTML File

```
<carousel>
  <slide>
    <img src="assets/images/wedding.jpg" alt="First slide" style="display: block; width: 100%;">
  </slide>
  <slide>
    <img src="assets/images/birthday.jpg" alt="Second slide" style="display: block; width: 100%;">
  </slide>
  <slide>
    <img src="assets/images/anniversary.jpg" alt="Third slide" style="display: block; width: 100%;">
  </slide>
```

when I am running the code it throwing following error.

> 'slide' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'slide' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
>     [ERROR ->]

Any help would be appriciated

Comment: Where did you declare HomeComponent? Consider importing CarouselModule there

Comment: that is declared in another module(EventModule) which i have imported in app.ts

Comment: Import CarouselModule in EventModule and it should work

Comment: thanks @yurzui.. it works, but i am not getting why importing in rootmodule is not working

Comment: You should read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601784/angular-2-use-component-from-another-module/39601837#39601837 or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153370/why-lazy-loaded-module-has-to-import-commonmodule-angular-2

Answer (score 1):

Change

From

```
import {CarouselModule}  from 'ngx-bootstrap/carousel';
```

To

```
import { CarouselModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
```

Because import **`{ CarouselModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/carousel';`** does not work with **`system.js`**

also add it under **`EventModule`** imports. And import **`EventModule`** inside app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

I don't know who through the same problem but here is the issue

in your homecomponnent.ts

import { CarouselConfig } from 'ngx-bootstrap/carousel';

and in your @component add this line

providers: [
{ provide: CarouselConfig, useValue: { interval: 2500, noPause: true, showIndicators: true } } ]
})

if you want to change the second of the slide you just need to change the interval number

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).