# Using ReactiveFormsModule on module lazyloaded

Tags: angular

I have this main module in Angular 4:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        //.. other modules
        ReactiveFormsModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ...routingComponents,
    ],
    providers: [
        ...routingGuards,
    ],
    exports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule,
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

I also have another module, AdminModule, that is lazy loaded from this main AppModule. On the AdminModule I have some routes where I also use the reactive form. However, when I try to create a new form I keep getting errors like these:

> Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

Trying to fix this problem, I saw that I had to export the ReactiveFormsModule from the main module in order to use with other modules, but I'm doing so and still getting the error. What am I doing wrong in here?

Comment: You have to import `ReactiveFormsModule` in the module were you have declared component that is used `[formGroup]` in template. Looks like you should import it in `AdminModule`

Comment: @yurzui within the `imports`? Because if I do, then it gives me errors unless I also declare a `import {} from`, which doesn't require me to export from the main module, since I'll be importing it again on the AdminModule. And if i don't declare `import {} from` i get compilation errors.

Comment: Why are you using `exports` in AppModule? Do you import AppModule somewhere?

Comment: Yes, add `ReactiveFormsModule` to `imports` array of `AdminModule @NgModule`

Comment: @yurzui but like I said, that will generate another import of the same module. What I'd like to do is to use the ReactiveFormsModule that is imported in the AppModule, isn't it possible to do?

Comment: You can use it only if you import AppModule in AdminModule but you should not do this. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601784/angular-2-use-component-from-another-module/39601837#39601837

Comment: But in this case, isn't it going to generate 2 chunks using the same code? In this case then I would need to create a third module, lets say `ShareModule`, where I import/export only shared modules used both in the AppModule and AdminModule? Ex.: RouterModule, ReactiveFormsModule.

Comment: Just try it. angular-cli has some problems with it but in common cases it should works well.

Comment: @yurzui Ok! Thanks for the advices :)

Comment: You can also use `source-map-explorer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We needed to import `ReactiveFormsModule` `FormsModule` in **AdminModule** in order to make all directives to work:

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    FormsModule,    //added here too
    ReactiveFormsModule //added here too
  ],
  declarations: [...],
  providers: [...]
})

export class AdminModule{}
```