# Angular component test with viewchild and directive

Tags: angular, testing

I made a plunker with my problem... https://embed.plnkr.co/UparfJDomOECGJfWSbqA/
Short: I am unable to test my component, it seems to fail in `container.component.spec.ts:43` - but without the `fixture.detectChanges()`, the `ngAfterViewInit` won't be started. I am unable to see what I am doing wrong.

I want to dynamically load a component into an ng-template with a directive attribute and the solution does work, but I am unable to write a working test for it.
Since I am pretty new to unit testing... Is that something I should even test - I think yes. (And yes I read the angular.io testing guide, and some others ;-) )
The error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'viewContainerRef' of undefined` which seems to point that `@ViewChild` does not have a ViewChild...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Testing module doesn't see `MenuDirective` because you forgot to export it from fake module:

```typescript
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MenuComponent,
        MenuDirective,
    ],
    exports: [MenuDirective], <== add this
    entryComponents: [MenuComponent]
})
class FakeEntryComponents {}
```

And seems you want to query MenuComponent

```typescript
menuElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MenuComponent))
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Oipzc9zRPa8mmsSwk5Kv?p=preview)**

See also

- [Angular 2 Use component from another module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601784/angular-2-use-component-from-another-module)
- [Angular Dynamic Component Injection error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45516705/angular-dynamic-component-injection-error)

Comment: Sir, you are a hero. Thank you so much