# Angular2 issue: There is no directive with “exportAs” set to “ngForm”

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I 'am facing this frustrating issue

> There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" ("
>                     
>                     
>                         ]#f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)"  class="form-horizontal">
>                             
>         "): ng:///ComponentsModule/EquipeComponent.html@8:12
>       Error: Template parse errors:
>       There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" ("
>                     
>                     
>                         ]#f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)"  class="form-horizontal">
>                             
>         "): ng:///ComponentsModule/EquipeComponent.html@8:12

This is what my ***app.module.ts*** contains

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { TabsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tabs';
import { NAV_DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES } from './shared/nav-dropdown.directive';

import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';
import { SIDEBAR_TOGGLE_DIRECTIVES } from './shared/sidebar.directive';
import { AsideToggleDirective } from './shared/aside.directive';
import { BreadcrumbsComponent } from './shared/breadcrumb.component';

// Routing Module
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';

// Layouts
import { FullLayoutComponent } from './layouts/full-layout.component';
import { SimpleLayoutComponent } from './layouts/simple-layout.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    TabsModule.forRoot(),
    ChartsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule                        
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FullLayoutComponent,
    SimpleLayoutComponent,
    NAV_DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES,
    BreadcrumbsComponent,
    SIDEBAR_TOGGLE_DIRECTIVES,
    AsideToggleDirective,
  ],
  providers: [{
    provide: LocationStrategy,
    useClass: HashLocationStrategy
  }],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I'am almost new to Angular2 so I can't figure out what is the problem with my code .

This is the content of ***equipe.component.html***

```
<div class="animated fadeIn">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <strong>Ajout Equipe</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="card-block">
                    <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="text-input">Nom Equipe</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input type="text" id="text-input" name="text-input" class="form-control" placeholder="Saisir le nom de l'equipe" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="textarea-input">Description</label>
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <textarea id="textarea-input" name="textarea-input" rows="9" class="form-control" placeholder="Description de l'equipe"></textarea>
                                </div>
</div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Ajouter</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!--/.col-->
        </div><!--/.row-->
    </div>
```

And this is the content of ***equipe.component.ts***:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
templateUrl: 'equipe.component.html',
})
export class EquipeComponent {

constructor() { }
onSubmit(f:NgForm) {
console.log('this is a test');
}
}
```

This is the content of my ***ComponentsModule***

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { ButtonsComponent } from './buttons.component';
import { CardsComponent } from './cards.component';

// Forms Component
import { FormsComponent } from './forms.component';
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';

import { SocialButtonsComponent } from './social-buttons.component';
import { SwitchesComponent } from './switches.component';
import { TablesComponent } from './tables.component';

// Modal Component
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { ModalsComponent } from './modals.component';

// Tabs Component
import { TabsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tabs';
import { TabsComponent } from './tabs.component';
// Ressource Component
import { RessourceComponent } from './ressource.component';
// Equipe Component
import { EquipeComponent } from './equipe.component';
// Components Routing
import { ComponentsRoutingModule } from './components-routing.module';

@NgModule({
imports: [
ComponentsRoutingModule,
BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
ModalModule.forRoot(),
TabsModule
],
declarations: [
ButtonsComponent,
CardsComponent,
FormsComponent,
ModalsComponent,
SocialButtonsComponent,
SwitchesComponent,
TablesComponent,
TabsComponent,
RessourceComponent,
EquipeComponent
]
})
export class ComponentsModule { }
```

Comment: The issue is in your HTML.  `#f="ngForm"` .  # is an alias for exporting a thing as a variable in the template, and you aren't using it properly.

Comment: @JasonSpradlin I'am following this [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm)

Comment: can you please show your code where you have used form in HTML? , even i follow this documentation but in my case everything working fine

Comment: @JasonSpradlin I'have added my HTML code

Comment: In which `@NgModule` did you declare `EquipeComponent`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **have to import `FormsModule` or other module that exportes `FormsModule` to
`@NgModule` where `EquipeComponent` has been declared**.

```typescript
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    // or SharedModule that exports FormsModule
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    EquipeComponent,
    SomeComponent
  ]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

In the preceding code angular will compile EquipeComponent template using SomeComponent directive and all directives that other modules has exported

```typescript
export const TEMPLATE_DRIVEN_DIRECTIVES: Type<any>[] = [NgModel, NgModelGroup, NgForm];
                                                                                ^^^^^
@NgModule({
  declarations: TEMPLATE_DRIVEN_DIRECTIVES,
  providers: [RadioControlRegistry],
  exports: [InternalFormsSharedModule, TEMPLATE_DRIVEN_DIRECTIVES]
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
})
export class FormsModule {
}

@Directive({
  ...
  exportAs: 'ngForm'
})
export class NgForm extends ControlContainer implements Form {
```

See also

- [Angular 2 Use component from another module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601784/angular-2-use-component-from-another-module/39601837#39601837)

Comment: after adding the declaration I get this error   
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type EquipeComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and ComponentsModule! Please consider moving EquipeComponent to a higher module that imports AppModule and ComponentsModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes EquipeComponent then import that NgModule in AppModule and ComponentsModule.

Comment: Error: Type EquipeComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and ComponentsModule! Please consider moving EquipeComponent to a higher module that imports AppModule and ComponentsModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes EquipeComponent then import that NgModule in AppModule and ComponentsModule.

Comment: I've added the declaration in my **_app.module.ts_**

Comment: @IbrahimMAATKI Import `FormsModule` into `ComponentsModule` Remove `EquipeComponent` from AppModule

Comment: returned to initial issue

Comment: @IbrahimMAATKI Can you share your ComponentsModule?

Comment: I've added my ComponentsModule in the question

Comment: I don't see ComponentsModule in your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151469/discussion-between-ibrahim-maatki-and-yurzui).

Comment: `This is the content of my app.component.ts` Where is ComponentsModule?

Comment: I don't see where did you import FormsModule here `@NgModule({
imports: [
ComponentsRoutingModule,
BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
ModalModule.forRoot(),
TabsModule
],`