# Angular 4 Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am new in using Angular 4. I am trying to practice model driven forms in angular 4, But it keep getting this error.

> Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a
>   known property of 'form'. ("
>         
>         
>           ][formGroup] = "form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
>               
>       "): ng:///ComponentsModule/AdsComponent.html@71:38 Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known
>   property of 'form'. ("
>         
>         
>           ][formGroup] = "form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">

I tried searching it for the issue on how to solve. Mostly the solution is by importing ReactiveFormsModule in the module.
Here is the code in my component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChange } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';                                                                                                                                                           


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'ads.component.html'
})
export class AdsComponent {
    form;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.form = new FormGroup({
            ads_name: new FormControl("Hello Ads!")
        });
    } 

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
    ) {

   }

   onSubmit = function(user) {
        console.log(user);
   }

}
```

and here is the code in my component.html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup] = "form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
   <div class="form-group row">
       <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="ads_name">Ads Name</label>
       <div class="col-md-9">
           <input type="text" id="ads_name" name="ads_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Ads Name" formControlName="ads_name" ngModel>
       </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

and here is the code in my module

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    TabsModule.forRoot(),
    ChartsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
```

Comment: which module is your `AdsComponent ` in?

Comment: I have a seperated component module inside my components folder seperated in the app inside of my views folder

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As your error states:

> Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a
>   known property of 'form'. (" ][formGroup] = "form"
>   (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)"> "):
>   ng:///ComponentsModule/AdsComponent.html@

we can assume that your `AdsComponent` is a part of `ComponentsModule` declaration but you have imported `ReactiveFormsModule` in `AppModule`. So in order angular will be able to compile template of `AdsComponent` you should:

1) either import `ReactiveFormsModule` in `ComponentsModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

2) or import module that is exporting `ReactiveFormModule`

```
@NgModule({
  exports: [
    ...
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    SharedModule
  ]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

See also:

[Angular 2 Use component from another module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601784/angular-2-use-component-from-another-module)

Comment: It solved the error. But theres another error. Here is the error No provider for ControlContainer. But I'll try to look at link you gave

Comment: This error is not related with that answer. You're doing something wrong in your template

Comment: can we have a conversation in the chatroom? If you're available sorry for bothering.

Comment: Try copying this code https://plnkr.co/edit/AKwwpmYp7liF6ADhBjpB?p=preview

Comment: I tried it already. Btw in my views folder I have a seperated components folder and in that folder I had each components with each controller and I had the components.module wher I placed to export the reactive forms module and import it using the sharedmodule that you gave above. Now I got this error. ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Unexpected value 'FormGroup' declared by the module 'ComponentsModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation. sorry for this

Comment: You should not add `FormGroup` to `declarations` array. Do you have github repo to reproduce it?

Comment: I think the error that I have now is a known issue in angular I am trying to search it of any solutions it said that is is more of a template error. This is the error No provider for ControlContainer

Comment: It's easy to reproduce. Check out console https://plnkr.co/edit/MtcCBlm0FZQ28qEv7lvp?p=preview I just removed `formGroup` from template and now `formControlName` directive can't find parent container https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.x/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_name.ts#L97

Comment: I figure it out I just put formGroup to the form of my other components and it solve the problem. Btw the links you gave and your answer helped me alot! Appreciated it!

Answer (score 1):

Please declare the ReactiveFormsModule as part of your testing module.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
        declarations: [YourComponent, ...],
        providers: [...]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are obviously multiple solutions. This worked for me. Import the `ReactiveFormsModule` in `app.module.ts`

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```