# Angular exported component from module not useable in another module

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-module

I am exporting a custom component in my AppModule but can not use it in another module, which is being imported in the AppModule. I thought exported components are visible globally?

I am trying to use the CalendarComponent with the selector 'app-calendar' in a component within the TestModule.

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ,
    CalendarComponent,
  ],
  imports: [ ... ,
    TestModule,
  ],
  exports: [ ...
    CalendarComponent,
  ],
  providers: [ ... ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

test.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ,
    TestComponent
  ],
  imports: [ ... ],
  exports: [ ... ],
  providers: [ ... ]
})
```

test.component.html

```
<app-calendar></app-calendar>
```

Console throws the error that 'app-calendar' is not a known element (not part of the module)

What am I missing?

Comment: TestModule should import module that is exporting Calendar component

Comment: you can read [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f)

Comment: @yurzui AppModule imports TestModule already so TestModule can not import AppModule since that would be a circular dependency or am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah, you're right

Comment: You should import the module of calendarComponent in tour page's module

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create `CalendarModule` or add `Calendar` component to your share module(depends on your architecture)  like:

**calendar.module.ts**

```typescript
@NgModule({
  declarations: [CalendarComponent],
  exports: [CalendarComponent]
})
export class CalendarModule {}
```

In `AppModule` remove `CalendarComponent` everywhere and import `CalendarModule`(or SharedModule) if some of declarations uses `CalendarComponent`

**app.module.ts**

```typescript
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ,
    CalendarComponent,  <== remove it
  ],
  imports: [
    TestModule,
    // import CalendarModule here if any of declarations above use CalendarComponent in their template
  ],
  exports: [ ...
    CalendarComponent,  // remove it
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**test.module.ts**

```typescript
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ,
    TestComponent
  ],
  imports: [ 
    CalendarModule <=== add this, so TestComponent will be able to use CalenderComponent in its template
  ]
})
export class TestModule {}
```

For more details see

- [Angular 2 Use component from another module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601784/angular-2-use-component-from-another-module)