# Angular module importing and component usage

Tags: angular, typescript, import, module, components

I have a directory structure as shown in image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yitTd.png

When I use `<app-news-card>` selector in **app.component.html**, it shows error of `<app-news-card> not present in current module.`

How should I fix this in the most best practical way.

Currently: 
I am

1.)exporting **news-card.component** from **news.module**

2.)then I have imported **NewsModule** in **current.module** with re-exporting **NewsModule**

3.)and then I have imported **CurrentModule** in **app.module**

Comment: Solution found from this thread:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46381730/angular-exported-component-from-module-not-useable-in-another-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46381730/angular-exported-component-from-module-not-useable-in-another-module)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the `news card` component in your declarations of your `news.module`. For example:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [NewsCardComponent],
  imports: [...],
  exports: [NewsCardComponent]
})
```

More information about boostrapping  can be found here: [Docs](https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping#the-declarations-array)

Comment: its present there and I have exported also.

Comment: Can you edit your answer and include news.module, current.module and app.module, or maybe provide a stackblitz or something?

Comment: Have a look at this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-imports)