# BrowserAnimationsModule does not work when imported in core module

Tags: angular, typescript, module, lazy-loading

I divided bigger app into modules (feature modules, core module and shared module). I am using Angular Material and therefore I imported `BrowserAnimationsModule`. I placed it in Shared Module and everything works fine, but the problem is arising when I want to lazy load some feature modules - then I have error about double import of BrowserModules. I know that BrowserAnimationsModule should be imported by Core Module, but when I am trying to do that, I get following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-option'.
1. If 'mat-option' is an Angular component and it has 'ngForOf' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-option' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("' | translate}}" (change)="change()" [(ngModel)]="actualFilter" name="food">
          <mat-option [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let filterColumn of displayedColumns" [value]="filterColumn">
            {{filterColumn | t"): ng:///ChargesModule/ChargesComponent.html@9:22
Property binding ngForOf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("COLUMNFILTER' | translate}}" (change)="change()" [(ngModel)]="actualFilter" name="food">
          [ERROR ->]<mat-option *ngFor="let filterColumn of displayedColumns" [value]="filterColumn">
            {{filt"): ng:///ChargesModule/ChargesComponent.html@9:10
```

Below I am presenting the modules:
app.module.ts:

```
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HomeModule,
        ChargesModule,
        ModeratorPanelModule,
        CoreModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })

    export class AppModule { }
```

core.module.ts:

```
 @NgModule({
      imports: [
        HttpModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        SharedModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        SidenavComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        ErrorPageComponent,
        PageNotFoundComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        UpdatePanelComponent,
        DialogConfirmCancelComponent,
        ConfirmMessageComponent,
      ],
      exports: [
        HttpModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        SharedModule,
        HeaderComponent,
        SidenavComponent,
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ],
      providers: [
        AuthService, AuthGuard, HttpAuthService, DictionariesService,
        DictionaryItemFactory, CanDeactivateGuard, { provide: MatPaginatorIntl, useClass: CustomPaginator }
      ],
      entryComponents: [DialogConfirmCancelComponent, ConfirmMessageComponent]
    })
    export class CoreModule { }
```

shared.module.ts:

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MaterialModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    TimepickerModule.forRoot(),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  exports: [
    NgbModule,
    TimepickerModule,
    TranslateModule,
    CurrenciesComponent,
    MaterialModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    FormsModule,
    DropDownListComponent,
    DictionariesComponent
  ],
  declarations: [
    DictionariesComponent,
    DropDownListComponent
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

In MaterialModule, I have imported all material modules together with CommonModule.

Comment: Did you forgot to import CommonModule?

Comment: Where? It is included in SharedModule

Comment: It is NOT exported from shared module. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601784/angular-2-use-component-from-another-module/39601837#39601837

Comment: Thanks, it worked. You can post this answer and I will mark it as solved. However, I do not understand why this problem occured only after moving of BrowserAnimationsModule from Shared to Core module. Can you explain that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you came across an error like

> Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property

then you should be aware that it either:

- has to do with undeclared `@Input`;
- or you have some problem with `@NgModule` configuration

Since `ngForOf` is a built-in directive let's analyze what's the problem with your `@NgModule` configuration.

First of all we need to determine where this error comes from. It's easy to see from the error message:

> {{filterColumn | t"): ng:///ChargesModule/ChargesComponent.html@9:22

It should be clear that we're getting error for `ChargesComponent` that is part of `ChargesModule`. I believe `ChargesModule` declaration looks like:

**charges.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    ChargesComponent,
    ...
  ]
})
export class ChargesModule {}
```

Now if you haven't read my previous answer [Angular 2 Use component from another module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601784/angular-2-use-component-from-another-module/39601837#39601837) i strongly suggest you to do it. Make sure you understand how one component/directive/pipe can be used in other module. If you do then just export `CommonModule` from `SharedModule`, if you are still in doubt then read on...

The main rule here is

**Since we need to use ngForOf directive within `ChargesComponent` template, that is part of ChargesModule, then this directive should be part of directives  in transitive ChargesModule.**

How those directives are collected?

```
               ChargesModule.directives 
                         + 
      exported directives from imported @NgModules
                        ||
         ChargesModule.transitiveModule.directives
```

At first glance we would declare `ngForOf` directive in `ChargesModule` declarations array but `ngForOf` is already declared in `CommonModule` and as directive has to be a part of only one module we can't do that.

Therefore continue looking `ngForOf` directives among imported `@NgModules`. Well, we imported `SharedModule` Let's see which directives it exports:

**shared.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  ...,
  exports: [
    NgbModule,
    TimepickerModule,
    TranslateModule,
    CurrenciesComponent,
    MaterialModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    FormsModule,
    DropDownListComponent,
    DictionariesComponent
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

`SharedModule` exports all directives that are either

exported from `@NgModules`

```
 NgbModule,
 TimepickerModule,
 TranslateModule,
 MaterialModule,
 FlexLayoutModule,
 CdkTableModule,
 FormsModule
```

*This means that if NgbModule has exported directives then they will be added to exported directives of SharedModule.*

or just directives included in `exports` array

```
 CurrenciesComponent,
 DropDownListComponent,
 DictionariesComponent
```

As we don't see here `CommonModule` we can assume we will get the error `Can't bind to 'ngForOf'`

To solve it we have to add `CommonModule` to exports array and all should work as expected.

The good question is

> However, I do not understand why this problem occured only after
>   moving of BrowserAnimationsModule from Shared to Core module. Can you
>   explain that?

It's hard to understand without knowing how `BrowserAnimationsModule` looks like. Let's achieve enlightenment by looking at [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.x/packages/platform-browser/animations/src/module.ts#L16-L21):

```
@NgModule({
  exports: [BrowserModule],
  providers: BROWSER_ANIMATIONS_PROVIDERS,
})
export class BrowserAnimationsModule {
}
```

and look at [BrowserModule](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.x/packages/platform-browser/src/browser.ts#L89-L91):

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  exports: [CommonModule, ApplicationModule]
})
export class BrowserModule {
```

It’s immediately obvious that if we export `BrowserAnimationsModule` module from `SharedModule` we also export directives from `CommonModule` since:

```
SharedModule.transitiveModule.directives
               /\
               ||
   BrowserAnimationsModule exports 
               /\
               ||
     BrowserModule that exports
               /\
               ||   
          CommonModule
```

So after moving `BrowserAnimationModule` to `CoreModule` your `SharedModule` doesn't export `ngForOf` directive anymore and that's why you're getting the error.

Comment: This answer exhausted the topic... Thank you really much for your help!