# @Input decorator not working at all

Tags: angular

I've been developing Angular apps some time already (especially now in the 5th version), and never found this problem before. Basically, I´ve got the following component...:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'super-table',
  templateUrl: './supertable.html',
  styleUrls: ['./supertable.css'],
  providers: [TableFormat]
})
export class SuperTable implements OnInit {

  @Input() defaultColumn;
  @Input() config;
  table: CrossSectionTable_controller;
```

... which receives this "config" object from outside. No problems with that approach; used it in all my components this far and it never gave any error. Now, when I try to use my table, I get an error:

```
  <div class="center-component"> 
    <super-table  [config]="config" [defaultColumn]="'kpi_expected_realized'">
    </super-table>
  </div>
```

> ERROR  Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'config' since it isn't a known property of
>   'super-table'.
>   1. If 'super-table' is an Angular component and it has 'config' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'super-table' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message.
>   3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
>
> ```
>   <div class="center-component"> 
>
>     <super-table  [ERROR ->][config]="config" [defaultColumn]="'kpi_expected_realized'">
>
>     </super-table>
>
>   </div>
> ```
>
> "): ng:///AchievedCombined_Module/AchievedCombined.html@36:22 Can't
>   bind to 'defaultColumn' since it isn't a known property of
>   'super-table'.
>   1. If 'super-table' is an Angular component and it has 'defaultColumn' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'super-table' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message.
>   3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("mponent-separator">
>
> ```
>   <div class="center-component"> 
>
>     <super-table  [config]="config" [ERROR ->][defaultColumn]="'kpi_expected_realized'">
>
>     </super-table>
>
>   </div>
> ```
>
> "): ng:///AchievedCombined_Module/AchievedCombined.html@36:40
>   'super-table' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'super-table' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'super-table' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message. ("
>
> ```
>   <div class="center-component"> 
>
>     [ERROR ->]<super-table  [config]="config" [defaultColumn]="'kpi_expected_realized'">
>
>     </super-table>
> ```
>
> "): ng:///AchievedCombined_Module/AchievedCombined.html@36:8
>   syntaxError@webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:684:34
>   TemplateParser.prototype.parse@webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:24547:19
>   JitCompiler.prototype._parseTemplate@webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:33975:16
>   JitCompiler.prototype._compileTemplate@webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:33950:18
>   JitCompiler.prototype._compileComponents/<@webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:33852:56
>   JitCompiler.prototype._compileComponents@webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:33852:9
>   JitCompiler.prototype._compileModuleAndComponents/<@webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:33722:13
>   then@webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:673:77
>   JitCompiler.prototype._compileModuleAndComponents@webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:33721:16
>   JitCompiler.prototype.compileModuleAsync@webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:33637:32
>   CompilerImpl.prototype.compileModuleAsync@webpack-internal:///../../../platform-browser-dynamic/esm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js:244:34
>   SystemJsNgModuleLoader.prototype.loadAndCompile/<@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:6637:44
>   ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:392:17
>   onInvoke@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4825:24
>   ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:17
>   Zone.prototype.run@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:142:24
>   scheduleResolveOrReject/<@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:873:52
>   ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:425:17
>   onInvokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4816:24
>   ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:17
>   Zone.prototype.runTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:192:28
>   drainMicroTaskQueue@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:602:25
>   ZoneTask.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:503:21
>   invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:1540:9
>   globalZoneAwareCallback@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:1566:17
>
> Stack trace:
>   resolvePromise@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:824:31
>   resolvePromise@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:795:17
>   scheduleResolveOrReject/<@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:873:17
>   ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:425:17
>   onInvokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4816:24
>   ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:17
>   Zone.prototype.runTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:192:28
>   drainMicroTaskQueue@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:602:25
>   ZoneTask.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:503:21
>   invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:1540:9
>   globalZoneAwareCallback@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:1566:17

As you see, it's happening too with the other Input variable...

What is going on here? Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46911583/browseranimationsmodule-does-not-work-when-imported-in-core-module/46914178#46914178

Comment: @Zerok have you added `SuperTable` to corresponding module's `declarations` list ?

Comment: @tchelidze You are right! How could I forget that... fixed now!

Comment: @Zero Great then, please mark the question marked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you add `SuperTable` component to corresponding module's declarations list .

```
@NgModule({
 declarations: [
    SuperTable
 ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```