# Angular2 - Unable to use directive in another component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

I have an angular app with following app module.

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';


// Import components
import {
  AppAsideComponent,
  AppBreadcrumbsComponent,
  AppFooterComponent,
  AppHeaderComponent,
  AppSidebarComponent,
  AppSidebarFooterComponent,
  AppSidebarFormComponent,
  AppSidebarHeaderComponent,
  AppSidebarMinimizerComponent,
  APP_SIDEBAR_NAV
} from './components';

const APP_COMPONENTS = [
  AppAsideComponent,
  AppBreadcrumbsComponent,
  AppFooterComponent,
  AppHeaderComponent,
  AppSidebarComponent,
  AppSidebarFooterComponent,
  AppSidebarFormComponent,
  AppSidebarHeaderComponent,
  AppSidebarMinimizerComponent,
  APP_SIDEBAR_NAV
]

// Import directives
import {
  AsideToggleDirective,
  NAV_DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES,
  ReplaceDirective,
  SIDEBAR_TOGGLE_DIRECTIVES
} from './directives';

const APP_DIRECTIVES = [
  AsideToggleDirective,
  NAV_DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES,
  ReplaceDirective,
  SIDEBAR_TOGGLE_DIRECTIVES
]

import {AppRoutingModule} from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...APP_CONTAINERS,
    ...APP_COMPONENTS,
    ...APP_DIRECTIVES
  ],
  exports: [],
  providers: [{
    provide: LocationStrategy,
    useClass: HashLocationStrategy
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

I want to use the directive `AsideToggleDirective` in the component of another module which is a child of the main `AppModule`.
I am able to use it properly in the components mentioned in `const APP_COMPONENTS`, but it does not work for another module components.

What am I missing here?

P.S. The other modules are defined by routes

Comment: You should create module that will declare and export AsideToggleDirective. Then import this module in AppModule and in another module See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601784/angular-2-use-component-from-another-module/39601837#39601837

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `AsideToggleDirective` to exports array :)