# Import component from sub-module in Angular

Tags: angular

So I've got my AppModule, module A, module B which is a submodule to A and component X declared in B.

My goal is to make X available app-wide (also in components like pages).

From my understanding, B needs X in declarations and exports, A needs B in imports and exports and AppModule needs A in imports. But the component X is unknown. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Your description should work. Where do you use X component? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwwwrs?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601784/angular-2-use-component-from-another-module/39601837#39601837

Comment: A can use B. However, AppModule Can only see A and what it exports

Comment: Huh, you're right. It actually works. Weird. The problem appears to be sitting somewhere else then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a `SharedModule`.

https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#sharedmodule

**SharedModule**

Create a `SharedModule` with the components, directives, and pipes that you use everywhere in your app. This `NgModule` should consist entirely of declarations, most of them exported.

The `SharedModule` may re-export other widget modules, such as `CommonModule`, `FormsModule`, and `NgModules` with the UI controls that you use most widely.

...

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { XComponent } from './XComponent';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [XComponent],
  exports: [XComponent]
})
export class ModuleX { }
```

---

```ts
@NgModule({
...
  imports: [
    ModuleX
  ]
...
})
export class AppModule { ... }
```

Comment: Well you could call my module A "SharedModule", but that doesn't solve the problem...

Comment: @fortuneNext I wouldn't make A a SharedModule. I would create a new Module X that exports ComponentX and import it into AppModule. This should solve your problem. "My goal is to make X available app-wide (also in components like pages)."