# How to use component in a in another module/router

Tags: angular, module, components

I'm trying to use another component from another module, but its not working in my router-outlet.

**app.module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MainModule } from './main/main.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { KeypadComponent } from './keypad/keypad.component;
import { routing } from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MainComponent,
    KeypadComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    MainModule,
    routing
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**main.module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { routing } from '../app.routing';

import { ProductComponent } from './product/product.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    routing
  ],
  declarations: [ProductComponent]
})
export class MainModule { }
```

My issue is that when I try to call the Keypad Component in `product.component.html`, it will give me an error that says it does not exist. However, when I call it in my `main.component.html`, it works fine.

Comment: your keypad component isn't declared in any module. And you should export it if you want to reuse it in another modules.

Comment: Oh sorry, it is. I gave another version of the files so I can show the focus of whats wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Use component from another module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601784/angular-2-use-component-from-another-module)

Comment: I've looked at that already it didn't seem to work

Comment: If the Keyboard component only needs to be accessed by the MainModule, move it in there instead of AppModule. If it needs to be used by both, move it to a shared module. If you are interested in the later approach, let me know and I'll post some sample code.

Comment: Yes please I need to know how to use it in a shared module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your component should be used by app module and main module it should go in the main module or in another shared module. Following example show how to use a shared module.

AppModule declaration

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MainComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MainModule,
    SharedModule,
    routing
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

MainModule declaration

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    routing,
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [ProductComponent]
})
export class MainModule { }
```

SharedModule declaration

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ CommonModule ],
  declarations: [ KeypadComponent ],
  exports: [ KeypadComponent ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```