# Angular Template parse errors: The pipe could not be found

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [Http]
      }
    })
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

about.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html',
})
export class AboutPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public translate: TranslateService) {
    this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad AboutPage');
  }

}
```

about.html

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{ 'HELLO' | translate }}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

</ion-content>
```

Error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: The pipe
>   'translate' could not be found ("
>
> {{ [ERROR ->]'HELLO' | translate }}
>
> "): ng:///AboutPageModule/AboutPage.html@3:18 Error: Template parse
>   errors: The pipe 'translate' could not be found ("
>
> {{ [ERROR ->]'HELLO' | translate }}
>
> "): ng:///AboutPageModule/AboutPage.html@3:18
>       at syntaxError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:82250:34)
>       at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:106433:19)
>       at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:116386:37)
>       at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:116361:23)
>       at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:116262:62
>       at Set.forEach ()
>       at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:116262:19)
>       at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:116132:19
>       at Object.then (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:82239:77)
>       at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:116131:26)
>       at c (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19752)
>       at c (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19461)
>       at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20233
>       at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15660)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5114:33)
>       at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15581)
>       at r.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10834)
>       at o (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7894)

Same code working like charm in root home page. Plaease help me How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Should that not be something like `.. | translate:param` where `param` is the actual value. This is what the [documentation describes](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#2-init-the-translateservice-for-your-application). I think you are confusing the "translation" to apply to `HELLO` here, where it **actually** applies to the `{ value: 'world' }` part.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 4):

I guess you should add `TranslateModule` to `imports` array of your `AboutPageModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    TranslateModule
  ],
  declarations: [AboutPage],
  ...
})
export class AboutPageModule {}
```

---

If you have shared module then you can add this module there

```
@NgModule({
  ...,
  exports: [
    ...,
    TranslateModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

and after that the following should also work:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [AboutPage],
  ...
})
export class AboutPageModule {}
```

See also:

- [Angular 2 Use component from another module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601784/angular-2-use-component-from-another-module)

Answer (score 1):

There are two things,

(i) you should import **`TranslateModule`** inside your submodules as well.

(ii) use **`HttpClientModule`**  instead of **`HttpModule`**

`import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http"`

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to export the Pipe in your TranslateModule

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem in the following way:

```
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        PipesModule
      ],
   ....
```

Here, **"PipesModule" is the key.**