# Angular - use component from another module

Tags: angular

i have a component contractDetails in contract module, i want to use this component in another module

i tried to export the contractDetails component but i get this error

> If 'contract-details' is an Angular component, then verify that it is
>   part of this module.

**contract.module.ts**

```
 @NgModule({
        imports: [
            CommonModule,
            ContractRoutingModule
        ],
        exports: [
            ContractDetailsComponent
        ],
        declarations: [
            ContractDetailsComponent
        ]
    })
    export class ContractModule { }
```

**contract-details.component.ts**

```
@Component({
        selector: 'contract-details',
        templateUrl: './contract-details.component.html'
    })
    export class ContractDetailsComponent {

    }
```

**organization.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        OrganizationRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        OrganizationDetailsComponent
    ]
})
export class OrganizationModule { }
```

**organization-details.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './organization-details.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./organization-details.component.scss']
})
export class OrganizationDetailsComponent {
}
```

**organization-details.component.html**

```
<contract-details></contract-details>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Use component from another module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601784/angular-2-use-component-from-another-module)

Comment: import `ContractModule` in your organization module.

Comment: @Igor this is not a duplicate. The question you linked has a different use case where he wants to use a component from a sub module while in this question, he wants to use a component from a sibling module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `OrganizationModule` needs to import the `ContractModule` to be able to use the `ContractDetailsComponent`. The `OrganizationModule` definition should be:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    OrganizationRoutingModule,
    ContractModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    OrganizationDetailsComponent
  ]
})
export class OrganizationModule { }
```

Comment: If for some reason he needs to import `OrganizationModule` into `ContractModule` then there will be circular dependency