# How to make a component visible in the entire package?

Tags: angular

I need to call a component in src from node_modules but using the selector won't work.

I tried adding the component to be accessed in sharedModule and have it imported at app.module.ts.

Comment: show us your `module.ts` files. Plus this is likely a duplicate e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601784/angular-2-use-component-from-another-module

Comment: Need more code and the name of the dependency in node_modules

Comment: I tried putting the component in declarations and exports, but it did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

in the app.module.ts you import Modules and components.
i.e.:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import {MyComponent} from './my-component.ts';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: []
})
```

But I think, this is something you already know.