# Ionic2: can't open next page: No component factory found

Tags: ionic2

I'm trying to develop my first app using ionic2. I start doing my first page and everything works fine, then I decided to add the second page and I faced an issue. When I click on the button which should open the next page, it is loaded but with the following error:

> Runtime Error
>
> Error in ./NewsHeadline class NewsHeadline - inline template:7:1 caused by: No component factory found for NewsPage
>
> Stack
>
> Error: No component factory found for NewsPage ...

```
Ionic Framework: 2.0.0
Ionic Native: 2.4.1
Ionic App Scripts: 1.0.0
Angular Core: 2.2.1
Angular Compiler CLI: 2.2.1
Node: 6.9.4
OS Platform: Linux 4.4
Navigator Platform: Win32
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
```

But I dont't understand exactly where I missing the NewsPage declaration.

This is my home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding> 
<ion-list>
    <h2 class="center">mY FIRST List</h2> 
    <ion-list> 
    <news-headline *ngFor="let notice of newsList" [news]="notice"> 
    </news-headline> 
</ion-list> 
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

this is my my app.modules.ts

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

import {NewsHeadline} from '../components/news/newsHeadline';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyApp,
        AboutPage,
        ContactPage,
        HomePage,
        TabsPage,
        NewsHeadline
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
        AboutPage,
        ContactPage,
        HomePage,
        TabsPage
    ],
    providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

While news-page.ts simply contains the following code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'; 
import { NavParams } from 'ionic-angular'; 
import {News} from '../../components/news/news'; 
    
@Component({ 
    selector: 'page-news-page',
    templateUrl: 'news-page.html'
}) 
export class NewsPage {
    news: News;
     
    constructor(navParams: NavParams) {
        this.news = navParams.data;
    }
}
```

So, the core of the problem is in my newsHeadline.ts file, which contains the following code:

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core'; 
import {News} from './news'; 
import {NewsPage} from '../../pages/news-page/news-page';  
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular'; 
 
@Component({ 
    selector: 'news-headline', 
    template: ` 
<ion-item> 
    <ion-thumbnail item-left> 
      <img src="{{news.imagePreviewUrl}}"> 
    </ion-thumbnail> 
    <h2>{{news.title}}</h2> 
    <p>{{news.date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</p>
    <button clear item-right (click)="goToNews(news)">Leggi</button>
</ion-item>` 
}) 
export class NewsHeadline { 
    @Input() 
    news: News; 
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}    
    
    goToNews(news: News) { 
        this.navCtrl.push(NewsPage, news); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add NewsPage to both declarations and entryComponents. You need to do this to every new page you create.

> UPDATE

[What is difference between declarations, providers and import in NgModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39062930/what-is-difference-between-declarations-providers-and-import-in-ngmodule)

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working :) Do you have a link or can you give a brief exaplanation about when adding entries to declarations and/or entryComponents?