# Why I cannot import Angular 2 service in @NgModule?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have `ExchangeService` Angular 2 `@Injectable` class and I have an application main module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        ExchangeService,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
   providers: [
    {   provide: LocationStrategy,
        useClass: HashLocationStrategy
    },
    ExchangeService
   ]
...})
```

which raises Exception

```
(index):16 Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected value 'ExchangeService' imported by the module 'Application5'
     Error: Unexpected value 'ExchangeService' imported by the module 'Application5'
     Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected value imported by the module Error: Unexpected value imported by the module
     Error: Unexpected value imported by the module at eval (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13982:37) at Array.forEach (native) at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata 
     Error: Unexpected value imported by the module at eval at Array.forEach (native) at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata
```

The exception disappears when I remove `ExchangeService` from the `imports` clause (and I leave in `providers` clause). I don't (at present) explicitly need `ExchnageService` to be in `imports` clause (I don't know what are benefits of it), I just want `ExchangeService` to be available for injection in other services in components globally.

The question is - **why I am not allowed write `ExchangeService` in `imports` clause?** `Imports` clause contains other TypeScript classes as well - like `HttpModule` and so on and why `imports` clause is not allowed to contain `ExchangeService` as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should import inside providers

Remove from

```
 imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,       
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ]
```

**imports:** is used to import supporting modules likes FormsModule, RouterModule, CommonModule, or any other custom-made feature module.

Read this [`what-is-difference-between-declarations-providers-and-import-in-ngmodule`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39062930/what-is-difference-between-declarations-providers-and-import-in-ngmodule)

Comment: I figured this out, but my question was - what is the difference between service ExchangeService and module BrowserModule - why I should import one and not import other?

Comment: services and modules are two different things

Comment: @TomR any reason to remove answer?

Comment: Many thanks for Your answer and clarification but other answer provided a bit more theory so I was pressed to mark it as accepted.

Comment: @TomR Thats fine! i have added the link to the description since i dont have to repeat the same

Answer (score 3):

- Using `imports` you can make other(FormsModule, HttpModule and etc) modules available in your current module.
- Using  `providers`you can inject the services required by components, other services, pipes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`imports` is used to import other angular modules in the current module.

`providers` is used to tell angular what types (in fact: instances) are available for dependency injection.

An `angular module` is an assembly of components, directives, pipes, services etc. It is an abstraction that helps to structure larger projects and to include functionality written elsewhere.

Every app consists of at least one module (the main module in your case). When the app grows you will be tempted to split in several modules though.

Your `ExchangeService` is presumably not a module, but just a service (a class with some methods). Other components and services of your application may depend on a concrete instance of ExchangeService and if you add ExchangeService to the providers array, Angular will create an instance of it and inject it as dependency when creating, for example, components (assumed you declared ExchangedService as a paramter to the constructor of the component).

I suggest to read https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html. The understanding of these architectural building blocks is - according to my 2 cents - necessary to use Angular successfully.