# What's the difference between Javascript import and angular import?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to Angular world. There is something which confuses me while learning it, why we need to import any module two times : once through Javascript `'import'` statement and then putting it in `'import'` array?

Why need to import the same thing two times? Same goes with other code parts : need to first import `'component'` and then again need to put the same in `'declarations'` array of `@NgModule`.

Why need to do that? I am not getting it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is difference between declarations, providers and import in NgModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39062930/what-is-difference-between-declarations-providers-and-import-in-ngmodule)

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're talking about your module files ?

First, you have this line

```
import { MyComponent } from './my-component.component';
```

this line allows the typescript compiler to say

> Okay, I need the resources from that file, in this file.

In this case, you're importing a class.

The next line is

```
declarations: [MyComponent]
```

(Or `imports` or `modules` or `providers` etc.)

In this case, this is related to **Angular** : as you can see, you put those "imports" into the decorator of your module, `@NgModule`. This is internal Angular stuff, but it allows him to do the correct things with your classes. For instance, when you put injectable classes into the `providers`, it tells Angular to create single instances of thoses classes.

Comment: Is it kind of lazyload? Will the component file loaded into the browser when module is loading?

Comment: No it's not. Lazy loaded modules are standalone modules that are loaded on route change (or according to your loading strategy).

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean Lazy load modules. I meant about the component files. Will the component and service files load into the browser when import fines?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The import doesn't depend on the decorator, but on the final bundle. Importing files at TS level only make them available for the compiler, to create a bundle.

Comment: I understood. Thank you. The following link helped me. Files are loaded dynamically/lazily. https://medium.com/lacolaco-blog/angular-dynamic-importing-large-libraries-8ec079603d0

Answer (score 0):

The keyword "import" is actually tells to import a module into the current module(module has class in it).
But after @NgModule whatever we are importing using imports keyword those are only single instances of the modules/classes imported previously.

Please correct me if I am wrong.