# How to import all modules from a directory in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) few techniques for importing modules are described:

- Import a single export from a module: `import { ZipCodeValidator } from "./ZipCodeValidator";`
- Import a single export from a module and rename it: `import { ZipCodeValidator as ZCV } from "./ZipCodeValidator";`
- Import entire module: `import * as validator from "./ZipCodeValidator";`

I expect there's one more option but nowhere I can find it. Is it possible to import all modules from a given directory?

I guess the syntax should be more or less like this: `import * from "./Converters"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript 1.8 modules: import all files from folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38158429/typescript-1-8-modules-import-all-files-from-folder)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

No this is not possible. What most people do is create an `index.js` file which re-exports all files in the same directory.

Example:

```
my-module/
  a.ts
  b.ts
  index.ts
```

a.ts

```
export default function hello() {
  console.log("hello");
}
```

b.ts

```
export default function world() {
  console.log("world");
}
```

index.ts

```
export { default as A } from "./a";
export { default as B } from "./b";
```

You can use the `*` character to re-export every export of a module with a single line. Be aware that TypeScript will error if a member with the same name has already been exported though *(thanks to @haysclark for the tip)*.

```
export * from "./somePath";
```

The index name can be dropped (same as in javascript):

```
import * as whatever from "./my-module";

console.log(whatever);
// Logs: { A: [Function: hello], B: [Function: world] }
```

Comment: how to write test case if all the added files are exported in index.ts as well ?
like if a d.ts and not added to index.ts how to avoid this situation programmatically

Comment: @Raghavendra Since everything is an `object` one can simply iterate over the keys. Something like: `import * as foo from "./bar";  console.log(Object.keys(foo).length) // logs import count`

Comment: this is not what i was asking 
take above answer as example i want to write test to check if they have added all a.ts, b.ts in index.ts file ?

Comment: I see. I'm not aware of any solution which does reliably can compare the exports. One could write a function that globs the directory and compares them with the exported functions, but that will always be somewhat fragile, in particular because you can export things under a different name. If you and your team are disciplined enough with the naming, the solution in my previous comment would do exactly that.

Comment: the question is how to make a check on the Team it self if they are adding all the exported function in index.ts or not 

so one solution i know is to parse the all files for export but that does not seems good

Comment: @marvinhagemeister ```export * from "./somePath";``` might be worth adding to your answer. :D

Comment: @haysclark Love this! Thanks a bunch for the suggestion. Just added it to the answer

Comment: It's worth noting that, depending on your build configuration, the use of index files can significantly increase your build times.  This is especially true if you're only using a few items from the selected folder.

Comment: Please never do this. It wreaks havoc with the intellisense (cmd + click leads to a file with just a bunch of exports - useless). It's a pattern I've seen often but never liked, what is so bad about importing your file directly from where it came from? Way easier to grok and immediately clear to see how your codebase is organized in any given file.

Answer (score 24):

I'm not sure if it safe to do for production code, but I use the following to import test code within a directory

```js
import glob from 'glob'

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  glob(__dirname + '/**/*.ts', function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
      reject(err)
    } else {
      Promise.all(
        res.map(file => {
          return import(file.replace(__dirname, '.').replace('.ts', ''))
        })
      ).then(modules => {
        resolve(modules)
      })
    }
  })
}).then(modules => {
  // do stuff
})
```

Comment: should be accepted answer imho. thanks for this

Answer (score 8):

Here's @tom-howard's answer with ES2022 syntax.

```js
import glob from 'glob';

let modules;

try {
  const res = await glob(__dirname + '/**/*.ts');
  modules = Promise.all(res.map((file) => (
    import(file.replace(__dirname, '.').replace('.ts', ''))
  )));
} catch (err) {
  // handle `err`
}

// use `modules`
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to import all from a folder using an `index file`, which is a bit more readable in my opinion:

**Folder structure:**

```
|-app.ts
|-layout
    |-navbar.ts
    |-sidebar.ts
    |-index.ts
```

**layout/navbar.ts**

```
export default () => ({ nav: 'bar' })
```

**layout/sidebar.ts**

```
export default () => ({ side: 'bar' })
```

**layout/index.ts**

```
import navbar from './navbar'
import sidebar from './sidebar'

export {navbar, sidebar}
```

**app.ts**

```
import * as layout from './layout'

console.log(layout.navbar()) // { nav: 'bar' }
console.log(layout.sidebar()) // { side: 'bar' }
```