# TypeScript: Can I import a folder without having to write an index.ts file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, import, directory

If most directories of a project contain no more than 2-3 TypeScript files and all of their exports should be accessible when importing the containing directory somewhere else, this results in a lot of `index.ts` files with predictable content.

### Example

Directory: `my-component`

```
my-component-config.ts
my-component.ts
index.ts
```

What does `index.ts` contain? Of course, it contains

```
export * from "./my-component-config"
export * from "./my-component"
```

Which is obvious.

For 10 component directories, that means: 10 `index.ts` files containing 100% redundant information.

**How can I make TypeScript(/Node) implicitly create `index.ts` files on the fly, that need not be stored on the hard disk?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Component* isn't a well defined concept in TypeScript & node.js, but **module** and **package** are.

In general, module is a source file, let's ignore the exceptions.   So by creating `index.ts` files per directory, you are generating façade modules aggregating only a few file/modules each.   If all you are looking to do is organize your source files into logical components, you don't need the per-directory façade, you can simply import each file individually rather than a directory at a time.

At a higher level, if you have a *package* that consists of a number of different directories, it can have a **single** `index.ts` façade at package-level.   That file would exported each file/module just once, no need for `index.ts` per directory.   So this might look like (assuming each is a .ts file):

```
export * from './IntStream';
export * from './misc/Interval';
export * from './misc/IntervalSet';
export * from './Lexer';
...
```

Comment: I see. Oftentimes I even import files individually rather than a directory at a time. But since I prefer dealing with short paths, usually no more than 2 segments, I prefer importing directories. I give you an example: Thanks to an `index.ts` file, I can import `lib/dialog/dialog.ts` using `import { Dialog } from "lib/dialog"` rather than `import { Dialog } from "lib/dialog/dialog"`. See the difference? And now imagine I do suchlike imports in hundreds of TypeScript files.

Comment: Did you mean `from "./lib/dialog/dialog"`.   I this its safest to use at least one façade so that any consuming module doesn't have any knowledge of the internal directory structure.

Comment: I mean `from "lib/dialog/dialog"`, since its parent folder is specified as a modules directory. Going without any façades does not burden me with a considerable safety loss. But using façades for small components burdens me with a considerable efficiency loss. I can guarantee safety by the use of access modifiers and `readonly`.

Comment: It's personal opinion, but I would recommend you **not** have external references that that dig into the directory structure (e.g. `from "lib/dialog/dialog"`.  IMHO, that exposes too much of package `lib`'s internal structure.   Its not a hard-and-fast rule, if you'd like to share a specific project on GitHub or something, I'd be happy to review and comment on your specific case.

Comment: Also recognize that your package-level façade may contain more than just the re-export statements.   E.g. it might be good to expose a higher-level function that uses your `dialog` class, rather than (or in addition to) exposing the class itself.

Comment: Usually, a component like my `lib/dialog` contains not much code: one class, some interfaces, some types. The class must be exported and there is no need to hide any of the interfaces/types because they are passive. If one of the components in `lib` has something to hide: exceptions are ok. But most components are like `lib/dialog`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a way to import a directory in TS without and index file

check these questions if you haven't

[How to import all modules from a directory in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40702842/how-to-import-all-modules-from-a-directory-in-typescript)

[Typescript 1.8 modules: import all files from folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38158429/typescript-1-8-modules-import-all-files-from-folder?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I think the best approach is to write a script to generate `index.ts` that imports all files in the directory, and run that script every time you add/remove a file.