# import images folder to backend controller and using all the files inside

Tags: typescript

how can i import a folder of images, tried this -

```
import * as img '../../images';
```

i want to get all the files inside of the folder and compare them to filenames.

how can i do that? maybe in another why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fs.readdirSync` to read the contents of a directory.

**Example:**

```js
import fs from "fs"

let images = fs.readdirSync("../../images")

console.log(images)
/* Example output
["sun.png", "stars.jpeg", "icon.psd"]
*/
```

[Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this [How to import all modules from a directory in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40702842/how-to-import-all-modules-from-a-directory-in-typescript)

The way you are trying is not possible.

Check this answer as well [Typescript 1.8 modules: import all files from folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38158429/typescript-1-8-modules-import-all-files-from-folder)