# Karma tests: measure coverage for untested code

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, karma-runner

I have successfully set up testing with Karma and Webpack for my [sandbox project written in Typescript](https://github.com/hoefling/chrome-extension-typescript). The code coverage metrics are collected by Istanbul Instrumenter Loader. What bothers me is that [I get the coverage reported only for the modules that are being imported in the tests](https://coveralls.io/github/hoefling/chrome-extension-typescript), so the reported coverage of 100% is in fact a dirty lie.

Looking for a solution, I have found a passage in Istanbul Instrumenter Loader's [readme](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/istanbul-instrumenter-loader/blob/master/README.md):

> To create a code coverage report for all components (even for those for which you have no tests yet) you have to require all the 1) sources and 2) tests.
>
> #### test/index.js
>
> ```javascript
> // requires all tests in `project/test/src/components/**/index.js`
> const tests = require.context('./src/components/', true, /index\.js$/);
>
> tests.keys().forEach(tests);
>
> // requires all components in `project/src/components/**/index.js`
> const components = require.context('../src/components/', true, /index\.js$/);
>
> components.keys().forEach(components);
> ```

If I understand correctly, this snippet walks over all index files in source dir and imports everything from them. My question is: how to correctly translate this snippet to Typescript? Or is there a better solution that does not require the `import * from *` workaround?

#### Edit

I've found this question: [Typescript 1.8 modules: import all files from folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38158429/typescript-1-8-modules-import-all-files-from-folder). Does this mean that I need an `index.ts` file where I have to import each module? This would mean that each time I introduce a new module file, I have to manually add its import to `index.ts`? There must be a better way.

#### Edit 2

I'm also open to other tools that can generate coverage report for the whole code base, the only condition them being able to cope with the Typescript + Webpack + Karma + Mocha stack. I have tried [**nyc**](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc), but couldn't manage to get any code coverage at all.

#### Edit 3

Here's the `index.js` from above translated to Typescript:

```
declare const require: any;

const ctx = require.context('../src', true, /\.ts$/);
ctx.keys().map(ctx);
```

#### Edit 4

There's a karma plugin now called `karma-sabarivka-reporter` that corrects the coverage statistics. Check out the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59011983/2650249) for details.

Comment: maybe just add test cases for all of your files and just do describe in those you would not want to test. what you are trying to achieve sounds a bit anti-pattern anyway, in sense you should only care about your test results.

Comment: I don't think that achieving true code coverage counts as an antipattern, here's what [React devs](https://coveralls.io/github/facebook/react) code coverage looks like, with [uncovered source files included](https://coveralls.io/builds/18457263/source?filename=packages/shared/ReactSharedInternals.js). Thing brings me actually to the idea of trying to replace Karma with [Jest](https://jestjs.io/).

Comment: I can personally strongly recommend Jest. It's very intuitive to use and it's basically `no configuration needed` setup. I have also used Jest to collect testing coverage of React translation -component of mine which worked great. You might also want to check out Airbnb/Enzyme which exposes some easier to use testing functions.

Comment: The pattern is to write each component spec test and based on the karma config file, webpack should pick up on all tests under /src as well as /tests. I tried your repo and it works as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For projects tested using Karma + Istanbul as coverage reporter – I've just created karma plugin, which adds all the files in the project to coverage statistic - https://github.com/kopach/karma-sabarivka-reporter.

To use it -> install `npm install --save-dev karma-sabarivka-reporter`

And update `karma.conf.js` like this:

```
reporters: [
  // ...
  'sabarivka'
  // 'coverage-istanbul' or 'coverage' (reporters order is important for 'coverage' reporter)
  // ...
],
coverageReporter: {
  include: [
      // Specify include pattern(s) first
      'src/**/*.(ts|js)',
      // Then specify "do not touch" patterns (note `!` sign on the beginning of each statement)
      '!src/main.(ts|js)',
      '!src/**/*.spec.(ts|js)',
      '!src/**/*.module.(ts|js)',
      '!src/**/environment*.(ts|js)'
  ]
},
```

Comment: Tested it with one of my projects that still use karma, it just works. Awesome! This should be merged into istanbul, seriously.

Comment: is there a way to 'disable' sabarivka when --code-coverage=false?

Answer (score 3):

## IMPORTANT:

This answer will not solve the above problem, it's fundamentally wrong. See comments.

---

NYC supports coverage for untested code with `--all` flag. Assuming your `test` command in `package.json` is

```
"test": "karma start karma.conf.js",
```

You can test coverage after `npm install -D nyc ts-node`, you can add the following command and run it. This command expects the source code to check for coverage to be in `src` directory.

```
"coverage": "nyc --all --include src --extension .ts --require ts-node/register npm test",
```

- `--all` flag is used to check all files for coverage.
- `--extension .ts` is for checking all TypeScript files, you can add more extension like `--extension .ts --extension .tsx`.
- `--include src` is for the directory to check for coverage.
- `-- require ts-node/register` is to teach NYC to understand TypeScript.

After that you should see all .ts files being included.

Note: Using `ts-node/register` may cause issues with line numbers on reports. To solve this you will probably need to register [source map support](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-support) as well..

Comment: This already looks more promising than everything I've seen so far; however, `nyc` doesn't pick up all source files - for example, `src/_modules/Utils.ts` is missing. Do you have any idea how to include all source files with `nyc`?

Comment: Oops. The reason NYC doesn't include all files is, it doesn't understand TypeScript syntax. Updating the answer to fix that issue.

Comment: Getting better - all files are picked up now, but it looks like the coverage is not collected: all files have zero code lines covered. At least `Utils.ts` should have some covered lines... When I leave `--include src` out, I see that `karma.conf.js` has 100% line coverage, which means something is collected.

Comment: I have included `--require source-map-support/register` and tried out some additional options, but with no awail - I've pushed the latest changes in `package.json` to master branch.

Comment: For source map support to consume, ts-node needs to create source maps correctly. Previously I had the best results with inline source maps. I will try to check out and put together an example

Comment: Taking a step back, I found out an important mistake. It's not possible to user NYC to check coverage with Karma. Karma runs tests in Browser which is a different process. Your best bet is changing Karma with Mocha (and JSDOM etc if needed) or trying some other coverage plugins for Karma.

Comment: That's a pity! However, thank you for your efforts - if there's no answer in the remaining time, I will grant you the bounty as it seems you're the only one who tried to help.