# Simplifying imports in app components through a shared Angular Material Module

Tags: angular, angular-module

I have a shared module like so:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { A11yModule } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { PortalModule } from '@angular/cdk/portal';
import { ScrollingModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import { CdkStepperModule } from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
import { CdkTableModule } from '@angular/cdk/table';
import { CdkTreeModule } from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';
import { MatBottomSheetModule } from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatDialogModule, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatNativeDateModule, MatRippleModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    A11yModule,
    CdkStepperModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    CdkTreeModule,
    DragDropModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    PortalModule,
    ScrollingModule,
    MatFormFieldModule
  ],
  exports: [
    A11yModule,
    CdkStepperModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    CdkTreeModule,
    DragDropModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    PortalModule,
    ScrollingModule,
    MatFormFieldModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

which I import in my `AppModule` . In turn this lets me use Material components in the various `.html` of my custom components. However, when using Material artifacts in Typescript files, it appears more needs to be done. In the below custom component, how could I replace import `{ MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';` with `import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from 'app/material.module';` ?

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { RuleSet } from 'app/objects/rule-set';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class ComponentXYZ {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ComponentXYZ>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: RuleSet
    ) {}

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

NB: here is my ts.config to explain the looks of my imports:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "./*",
        "app/*"
      ],
 (...)
```

Comment: I don't understand your requirement. What is the goal to replace import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog'; with import { MaterialModule } from 'app/material.module'; (this is not possible by the way)

Comment: As you need to reference MatDialogRef and MAT_DIALOG_DATA into your ts file, you need to import them explicitly.

Comment: There can be multiple classes in different libraries with same name, so when you refer to MatDialogRef in the code Angular would not know to pick this class from which module/library. You might be thinking in terms of import * as mat from @angular/material/dialog, then you probable need to look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38158429/typescript-1-8-modules-import-all-files-from-folder

Comment: thanks for the initial comments. What about substituting with `import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from 'app/material.module';` ? The idea is to clean up imports throughout a number of components that leverage several third-party UI dependencies, in a team of 5 people. It also makes it easier and cleaner to add the right stuff without thinking too much in .`spec.ts` files